# How to verify valid PDF and calculate E(X^4) base on E(X^2)

Tags: integration, statistics, random-variables, expectation

a past exam question has the question in the below image. I am very stuck on how to do both parts. I know a valid pdf  is greater than 0 for all x and the integral between -infinity and infinity is equal to 1. How would I prove that here? Also, any pointers on what to use to integrate part ii?

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ycHk.png)

Comment: Sorry, not interested in answering images. Please re-state question, with emphasis on what's puzzling you.

Comment: The image is illegible. Please fix it.